# How to fix ubuntu-advantage-tools?

Tags: 14.04

How do I fix this error:

> E: The package ubuntu-advantage-tools needs to be reinstalled, but I
>   can't find an archive for it.

I'm trying to reinstall ubuntu-advantage-tools and I used these commands:

i did

```
    aptitude remove ubuntu-advantage-tools
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

But it didn't work

I found this website 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/ubuntu-advantage-tools
then i download the pack for server but i dont know how to install there is no .sh to do it

Comment: Did you remove it with `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-advantage-tools` first? Also can you post the Error you're getting?

Comment: `But it din't work ` .. what did happen ? Please update your question with the output and errors of the commands.

Comment: yes i deleted it first